# FireDAC Left Join TDBGrid Assending Sort Order of columns with no joined data are at the bottom?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac

I setup a `LEFT JOIN` between two tables that are used in a `TDBGrid` and it all works except the sort order of the joined string column is not as expected.   In ascending order the blank entries, those that didn't have a match on the joined table, are below items with text.   Likewise if you sort in descending order they show at the top instead of the bottom.   It seems like *blank* entries should be listed first when sorting on that column in ascending order?  If not, what is the reason and is there a way to get it to sort as expected?

Comment: Space has a lessor value. Add DESC to your SQL and it will be the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your SQL engine returns that data. Remember that null values are considered an unfilled state instead of a real value.

The SQL standard allows you to add NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST to your `ORDER BY` clause. Example:

```
ORDER BY LastName ASC NULLS FIRST
```

But many SQL engines doesn't recognize that clause, so you have to code a workaround, like converting the null values to empty strings, so they will be ordered normally.

```
ORDER BY coalesce(LastName, '') ASC
```